# How to put "saved my time" in sentence?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

If I want to say that I have to scan my computer for virus filtering but some information tell me that there is no virus issue in my system and saved my time because I don't need to do virus filtering then is this the correct sentence to say

```
It save my time of virus filtering?
```

or is there any other way to say that more accurately and neatly?

Comment: You may wish to check out [our sister site for English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). It’s “for people who are learning or teaching English as a foreign language”, whereas we’re “for linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts”.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that could be better answered on ELL.

Comment: Are you saying that you installed Linux? :)

Comment: tchrist what makes you think the OP is not an English native speaker? The errors could be dictated by either haste or carelessness.

Answer (score 2):

To remain as close as possible to your original word selection I would go with

> It saved me the time of virus filtering

or perhaps

> It saved me the time of performing a virus scan

Answer (score 1):

Your original sentence

```
It save my time of virus filtering?
```

is not correct standard English. The closest correct format would be, for example:

> It saves the time of scanning for viruses.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you might really have in mind. In any case, I would give it a shot and hope that it fits your description.

> That piece of information really saved my time [because I didn't have to scan my computer for viruses].
>
> You really saved my time with that software package you gave me because I didn't have to scan my entire computer for viruses.
>
> I didn't have to go through the hassle of scanning my computer for viruses.

Answer (score 0):

It was a real time-saver. (I didn't need to scan for viruses.)